# Google Ads API - can I specify 'matchType' while looking for keyword traffic in GenerateKeywordIdeas?

Tags: python, keyword, google-ads-api, match-types

I may be doing it the wrong way but I want, at first, to extract keyword traffic information like I did with `TrafficEstimationService` in the (now deprecated) AdWords API. My code looks like this (with some edits here and there):

```
# [... some initialization (clients, service accounts, etc.) bits here]

# fetch an instance of the Google Ads client
gc = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage(gads_credentials_file, version="v10")

# fetch an instance of the Google Ads service
gs = gc.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

# fetch an instance of the Geo Target Constant service
gtcs = gc.get_service("GeoTargetConstantService").geo_target_constant_path

# fetch an instance of the keyword plan idea service
ks = gc.get_service("KeywordPlanIdeaService")

# build the initial search request
rq = gc.get_type("GenerateKeywordIdeasRequest")
rq.customer_id = gads_account_id.replace("-", '')
rq.geo_target_constants = [gtcs(get_location_id(gads_country))]
rq.keyword_plan_network = (gc.enums.KeywordPlanNetworkEnum.GOOGLE_SEARCH_AND_PARTNERS)
rq.language = gs.language_constant_path(get_language_id(gads_language))
rq.keyword_annotation = gc.enums.KeywordPlanKeywordAnnotationEnum

if len(gads_keywords) > 0:
    rq.keyword_seed.keywords.extend(gads_keywords)

# generate keyword ideas
keyword_ideas = ks.generate_keyword_ideas(request=rq)
rows = []

for idea in keyword_ideas:
    rows.append({
        "date": r,
        "text": idea.text,
        "competition_value": idea.keyword_idea_metrics.competition.name,
        "avg_monthly_searches": idea.keyword_idea_metrics.avg_monthly_searches
    })
```

So far, so good. I can specify location and language and (of course) they keywords to look for. At the end of this request, I have something like this (just printing the first list item):

```
{'date': '2022-08-09', 'text': 'zapatos', 'competition_value': 'MEDIUM', 'avg_monthly_searches': 301000}
```

The problem I have is I have been requested to ensure the match type is EXACT but looking at both the documentation and the source code for `KeywordPlanIdeaService` there is no trace of this parameter. That's why I assume I'm doing it wrong (or maybe I'm lacking something here). In any case, I'm a bit lost.

Can you tell me how can I specify this (if it can be done) or an alternate way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The output will be what Google Ads now calls exact match (which really isn't that exact anymore) - I believe they don't give you searches for *only the keyword* as that isn't really an option in their advertising as well.

The avg. monthly searches you receive will be for the keyword + close variants, and if you want to check which variants are included you can using this: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/GenerateKeywordHistoricalMetricsResult